# Write an outputstream after reading bluetooth socket android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I want to write after reading from a device (via Bluetooth socket )
The problem is that the while(true) finish when the socket is closed so I can't Write again.

This is the code:

```
        try {
            // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
            // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            try {
                connectingThread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outstream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            outstream.write("P".getBytes());
            instream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[128];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
            String readMessage = "";

             // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = instream.read(buffer);
                    if(bytes!= -1){
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                    arrayList.add(readMessage);
                    biodyMsg = TextUtils.join("", arrayList);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.d("Read Error", e.toString());

                }finally {
                    outstream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                    outstream.write("F".getBytes());
                }
                break;
            }

        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();
            try {    
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0p9r.png)

Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

The only way a `while (true)` loop can terminate is via a `break` statement, or by getting an uncaught exception, and you haven't mentioned getting one. There are two possible exceptions in this code:

- `IOException`: but the only way you can get an `IOException` with this code is if the peer *resets* the connection.
- `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when constructing the `String`, if `bytes` is negative, which it can be: see below; but you haven't mentioned this either.

Your actual problem is that you aren't checking `bytes` for -1, which would indicate end of stream, which in turn would indicate that the peer has closed the connection, which in turn indicates that you should close the socket and break out of the read loop.

Comment: sorry for not putting the exception :                                                                              java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Comment: So the peer has reset the connection. What's your question?

Comment: Can i write before the reset of connection i want to send "F" after finishing the read

Comment: Of course not. It's reset. Once you get that condition there is no connection.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using socket in Android can you help me please to find a solution or any suggestion  .

Comment: If the peer has reset the connection it is usually because you sent him something wrong earlier. An application protocol error. Check the logs at the peer.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit and i can send after reading but not reading all the bytes (little problem) : first i send P to device so it can send me the data then i finish by sending an F to erase the content of this device, that's how it work